# Gibt es ein deutsches Äquivalent zu einem »Date«?

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice

Gibt es ein deutsches Äquivalent zu einem *Date* im Sinne einer romantischen Verabredung? Auf Englisch würde ich z. B. fragen:

> Would you like to go on a date sometime?

Eine Übersetzung dafür wäre:

> Hättest du mal Lust auf ein Date?

Aber das passt eher zu Teenagern und nicht zu einer Verabredung zwischen zwei Personen, die über 25 sind. *Verabredung* ist mir nicht genau genug, da das zu unverbindlich klingt. Gibt es da was Passenderes?

Comment: Beachte, dass es auch erhebliche über das sprachliche hinausgehende Unterschiede zwischen amerikanischen und deutschen Balzritualen gibt. Es gibt also im Deutschen nicht nur keine direkte Übersetzung für das amerikanische *date,* es gibt auch derartige *dates* schlichtweg nicht oder zumindest kaum. (Ich bin mir gerade nicht sicher wie es in der britischen Kultur ist.)

Comment: Kein Duplikat aber verwandt: [Accurate words to communicate the concept of “dating”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/10612/2594).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Kannst du vielleicht kurz auf die amerikanischen Dates eingehen? Ich hab noch nie "amerikanisch gedated", kann mir grad nicht vorstellen, was das bedeutet...

Comment: @Em1: Im verlinkten Post (und in Roberts Antwort) wird das umrissen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das ganze Konzept von Dating ist im Deutschen nicht so wie im (US) Englischen. Da hängt in der US-Kultur eine ganz andere Erwartungshaltung dran, von wegen ab dem wievielten Date ist Sex dabei, ist double dating ok, wer bezahlt, etc.

Von daher würde ich keine direkte Übersetzung suchen, sondern es anders formulieren: "Willst Du mit mir ausgehen / ins Kino gehen / zum Essen gehen?"

Comment: Zwar richtig, aber ich frage mich gerade, ob "Willst du"-Fragen wirklich gängig sind.

Comment: @Em1 Wieso nicht? Wie würdest Du fragen? "Gehst Du mit mir ins Kino?" "Hast Du Lust, mit mir ...?"

Comment: Aus dem Bauch heraus sind das auf jeden Fall Alternativen, wenn ich mir ziemlich sicher bin, dass die Antwort Ja sein wird. Wenn ich es schlecht einschätzen kann, würde ich den Konjunktiv einsetzen. Ich werd nächstes mal drauf achten ;) Anyway, ich hab das eigentlich angemerkt, weil "Willst du" irgendwie auf mich so Tenniemäßig klingt. Vielleicht ist das auch nur meine persönliche Auffassung.